# CSS float is reversed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want put div with class name `rangechart_box` in the top right range slider but when i use of `display: inline-block` and `float: right` together It is reversed downward, What do I do to put in the top right range slider?

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/g4xx50Ld/3/

I want it as this but with `float:right` and without `margin-right:-5px` in class name `rangechart` :https://jsfiddle.net/g4xx50Ld/4/

```css
#slider-range{
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  background: #000;
  height: 6px;
}
.rangechart_box {
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
.rangechart {
    background: #ea8755;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    //margin-right: -5px;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="rangp" style="width: 100%;">
 <div class="rangechart_box">
  <div class="rangechart" style="height: 14px;"></div>
  <div class="rangechart" style="height: 18px;"></div>
  <div class="rangechart" style="height: 24px;"></div>
 </div>
  <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>
```

I want it putting in the top and right without spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should go for css flexbox:

```
.rangechart_box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.rangechart {
    background: #ea8755;
    width: 20%;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g4xx50Ld/10/

Answer (score 2):

New Edit 3: https://jsfiddle.net/g4xx50Ld/12/

```
.rangechart_box {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Notice the

```
 <div class="rangechart_box"><div class="rangechart" style="height: 14px;"
    ></div
    ><div class="rangechart" style="height: 18px;"></div
    ><div class="rangechart" style="height: 24px;"></div>
  </div>
```

You have to get rid of the spaces between the divs.
You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

Comment: no, I want it putting in the top and right without spaces.

Comment: In the your code is space between `rangechart`. I do not want it.

Comment: Yes that's right, but i mentioned above that I do not want to use of `margin-right`.

Comment: Updated simple solution. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 1):

Use *clearfix*.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
}
```

Then add this class to your div like this.

```
<div class="rangechart_box clearfix">
```

Comment: tnx but this just put right and top but it still is reversed, SEE:https://jsfiddle.net/g4xx50Ld/6/

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
.rangechart {
    background: #ea8755;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g4xx50Ld/7/